# adjusting ubuntu server resolution in VMware

Tags: screen

What are the steps to change resolution of Ubuntu server 16 to a desired resolution in Virtual machine. Am using Vmware. I tried to follow steps in this forum but that never worked. So i figured out maybe asking again may help, because there are new ideas out there everyday.

Comment: Which "steps in this form" are you referring to?

Comment: **1)** Please note that askubuntu.com is _not a forum_ nor a discussion board. It's a collection of questions and answers. **2)** It would be of great help if you'd tell us what steps you followed that didn't work so we don't tell you the very same things again. Currently you are asking _"I did something, but it didn't work."_ What is that _something_?